# Nginx parse url for parameters

Tags: nginx

I've placed a file at example.com/confirmed.php. I would like this file to handle any request for

example.com/confirmed/foo
or
example.com/confirmed/bar

**I don't want either of those urls to change when someone lands on them**. I just want to request handled by confirmed.php where I can parse the url and capture the foo or bar values (that part I can do). However, I cannot figure out how to write the location block in nginx. Here is what I have tried:

```
location /confirmed/{
    try_files confirmed.php;
}
```

or

```
location /confirmed/*{
    try_files confirmed.php;
}
```

I am completely new to nginx and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have look at this documentation for [Passing Uncontrolled Requests to PHP](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#passing-uncontrolled-requests-to-php).

Comment: Try: `location /confirmed/ { rewrite ^ /confirmed.php last; }`